# jquery dialog with jcrop size issue

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm uploading the image file and then previewing on jquery dialog for cropping using jcrop. For small size its working fine but when i'm uploading large file the dialog become stretch.

header includes:

```
<head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<html:rewrite page='/scripts/crop/jquery.Jcrop.js'/>"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<html:rewrite page='/scripts/jquery-plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js'/>"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" src="<html:rewrite page='/styles/crop/jquery.Jcrop.css'/>"/>
            <%--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  src="<html:rewrite page='/styles/crop/jQueryUI.css'/>"/>--%>
            <style type="text/css">
                @media print {
                    .label.active {
                        background-color: transparent !important;
                        border-right: white !important;
                    }
                }

                table.form img {
                    width: 128px;
                    height: 128px;
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
                }
                .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
                    max-width: 500px !important;
                    max-height: 600px !important;
                    /*width: 600px !important;*/
                }
     </style>
```

javascript code:

```
    <script language="Javascript">

                var jcrop_api;
                function initJcrop()
                {

                    jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#cropBox',{
                        onChange: setCoords,
                        onSelect: setCoords

                    })

                    jcrop_api.setOptions({
                        allowSelect: true, allowMove: true, allowResize: true, aspectRatio: 1
                    });
                }
//            });
            function setCoords(c)
            {
                jQuery('#x1').val(c.x);
                jQuery('#y1').val(c.y);
                jQuery('#x2').val(c.x2);
                jQuery('#y2').val(c.y2);
                jQuery('#w').val(c.w);
                jQuery('#h').val(c.h);
            };

            function imageHandler(e2)
            {
                initJcrop();
//                var elem = ;
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    show: {
                        modal:true,
                        resizable: true
                                    ,
                        maxWidth:600,
                        maxHeight: 500,
                        width: 600,
                        height: 500
//                        effect: 'fade',
//                        duration: 2000
                    } ,
//                    maxHeight:document.getElementById('cropBox').height,
//                    maxWidth:document.getElementById('cropBox').width,
                    close: function( event, ui ) {
                        jcrop_api.destroy();
                        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                    }
                });
//                elem.dialog('open');
            }

     function readFile(){

                var preview = document.querySelector('#cropBox');
                var file = document.querySelector('#imageId').files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
//              fr.readAsDataURL(filename);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    preview.src = reader.result;
                    imageHandler();
                }
                if (file) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    preview.src = "";
                }
                    document.getElementById("isSubmit").value = "false";
            }

            function cropPic(){
                document.getElementById("postForm").submit();
            }

                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
            function closeDialog(){
                jcrop_api.destroy();
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');

            }

    function setCoordinates(c) {
                //alert("x " + c.x + " y " + c.y);
                //alert("w " + c.w + " h " + c.h);
                document.myForm.x.value = c.x;
                document.myForm.y.value = c.y;
                document.myForm.w.value = c.w;
                document.myForm.h.value = c.h;
            };

            function checkCoordinates() {
                if (document.myForm.x.value == "" || document.myForm.y.value == "") {
                    alert("Please select a crop region");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            };

        </script>
```

html

```
<span id="reuploadImg" ><html:file name="uf" property="file" size="37" onchange="readFile()"  styleId="imageId"  /></span>
                 <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="x1" id="x1"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="y1" id="y1"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="x2" id="x2"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="y2" id="y2"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="w" id="w"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="h" id="h"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="isSubmit" id="isSubmit" value="true"/>
                </td>

  <div id="dialog" style="display: none;max-height: 600px;max-width: 600px" title="Preview" >
        <img id="cropBox" style="max-height: 600px;max-width: 600px"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center">
            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="cropPic()" class="stdbutton"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="closeDialog()" class="stdbutton"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here are the images: 
[image: Works fine]
[image: Title goes out with small size.]
[image: Extra black image appears]

Comment: Why you have CSS max-width css styles? They blocks auto-resizing.

Comment: To avoid the size after the certain level